# TTransportException: Could not connect to "impala01":21050

Tags: python, impala

```
from impala.dbapi import connect

conn=connect(host="impala01",port=21050,user='username',password='password')

error: TTransportException: Could not connect to "impala01":21050
```

Although connecting "impala01" is successful from the shell,but through python it gives me this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried to specify a fully qualified host name (impala01.xxxxxx.com)?

Comment: Yes @mazaneicha is correct. You have to give the full server name.